# How to for loop check array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two array:

```
var listOfObjects = [{ "name": "A", "data": [{'value1':'1','value2':'2'}] },
                     { "name": "B", "data": [{'value1':'','value2':''}] }];
var markedImage = ["A","B","C"];
```

and this is my code:

```
function checkData() {
        var invalidDoc = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < listOfObjects.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < markedImage.length; j++) {
                if (listOfObjects[i].name== markedImage[i]) {
                    for (var k = 0; k < listOfObjects[i].data.length; k++) {
                        if (listOfObjects[i].data[k] == "") {
                            var invalidfile = markedImage.indexOf(listOfObjects[i].name);
                            invalidDoc.push(invalidfile);
                            break;
                        } else {
                            var valid = markedImage.indexOf(listOfObjects[i].name);
                            validDoc.push(valid);
                        }

                    }

                } else {
                    var invalidfile = markedImage.indexOf(listOfObjects[i].name);
                    invalidDoc.push(invalidfile);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is check both array.

First check is : If item in `markedImage` is not exist in `listOfObjects`, push the index of `markedImage`into `invalidDoc`.

Second check is : the data of listOfObjects cannot be empty, if it is empty push the index of `markedImage`into `invalidDoc`.

For example,

Expected result for `invalidDoc` is [1,2]. Because data of "B" in `listOfObjects` is empty, "C" is not exist in `listOfObjects`. 1 and 2 is the index of "B" and "C" in `markedImage`.

Comment: a expected output array is better than words below:                       
                  invalidDoc will have 1 and 2 inside. Because data of "B" in listOfObjects is empty, "C" is not exist in listOfObjects. 1 and 2 is the index of "B" and "C" in markedImage.

Comment: @xianshenglu he did. *For example, invalidDoc will have 1 and 2 inside.*

Comment: you mean [1,2]?

Comment: @xianshenglu yes..

Comment: Is you `data` an array or a string?

Comment: @KirillSimonov is an array

Comment: and by empty do you mean an empty array or an array with objects that have empty fields?

Comment: @KirillSimonov an array with objects that have empty fields

Comment: check my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example. I used the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function over the `markedImage` array to find elements that are not present in the `listOfObjects` and check the `data` arrays.

`isDataEmpty` is a function which does the validation of every `data` array. You can change its logic according to the desired result.

```js
var listOfObjects = [{ "name": "A", "data": [{'value1':'1','value2':'2'}]}, //not empty
                     { "name": "B", "data": [{'value1':'','value2':''}]},   //empty
                     { "name": "D", "data": []},                            //empty
                     { "name": "E", "data": [{'value1':'1','value2':'2'}]}, //not empty
                     { "name": "G"},                                        //empty
                     { "name": "H", "data": [{'value1':'','value2':''}, 
                                             {'value1':'1','value2':'2'}]}];//empty
var markedImage = ["A","B","C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"];

function isDataEmpty(data) {
    // You can add any validation conditions here.
    // I assume that your data is an array and that by empty
    // data you mean that array may be empty, undefined,
    // or have some objects with empty 'value1' or 'value2'
    return !data ||
           data.length === 0 || 
           data.some(function(d){return d.value1 === "" || d.value2 === ""});
};

function find(array, name) {
    for (var i in array) {
        if (array[i].name === name) return array[i];
    }
    return null;
}

var invalidDoc = markedImage.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
    var found = find(listOfObjects, cur);
    if (!found || isDataEmpty(found.data)) {
        acc.push(i);
    }
    return acc;
},[]);

console.log(invalidDoc);
```

Comment: for some reason.. i can't use the => arrow function.

Comment: Then you can replace it with a regular function, eg `(data) => {` becomes `function(data) {`

Comment: @Xion Well, then you can change them to `var`, all logic stays the same. Check my updated code.

Comment: The find methos is not supported in IE...and what if my listOfObjects is like this `[{ "name": "A", "data": [{'value1':'1','value2':'2'},{'value1':'','value2':''}] }]; `.

Comment: @Xion should this object be considered emty?

Comment: The example H should considered empty because one of the element have empty field. Actually I have 7 item inside the data.

Comment: @Xion `filter` function can be easily replaced with a `for` loop (see my update). As for emptiness - my code already takes into account cases like your example. It considers an array empty if it has at least one element with empty `value1` or `value1` filed (I left comments there in my code).

Comment: @Xion what do you say? I believe my efforts to help you are worth at least an upvote ;)

Comment: yes..it works..bt i have to change the code to `if (array[e].name== name) return array[e];` in order to work..

Comment: @Xion I guess that's because you use [for..in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/for-dot-dot-dot-in-statement-javascript) loop instead of [for..of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/for-dot-dot-dot-of-statement-javascript). First iterates through object keys and second - through values

Comment: ya..cause IE not suport for..of.. :)

Comment: they do not keep up with time